# change function defination based on type trait?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, type-traits

I would like to change my function definition based on type by using `enable_if_t`. Some thing similar to this:

```
#include<type_traits>
template<typename T> struct A;

template<typename T>
struct A{
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, bool>
    test()
    {
        return true;
    }
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,  bool>
    test()
    {
        return false;    
    }

};
```

Currently [it cannot compile at all](https://godbolt.org/z/wJejKC).

Comment: Class methods with the same name and signature are not allowed. A function's return type is not a part of its signature. The easiest solution here is to declare the return type as `auto`, and use `if constexpr` to return the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, bool>
test()
 { return true; }

template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<U>::value,  bool>
test()
 { return false; }
```

I mean... SFINAE works over template parameter of the functions/methods, not over template parameters of the class containing the methods.

With `typename U = T` you transform `T`, the class template parameter, in `U`, a method template parameter.